# How to check if someone blacklisted/banned from visiting UAE?

Tags: uae, visa-bans

Is it possible to check that online? If, say , I travelled to UAE only by tourist visa, in what cases I can be blacklisted/banned from travelling there again by tourist visa next time?

Comment: If you have not done anything wrong and you have not been served with any papers why would you fear that?

Comment: For privacy reasons, it would be highly unlikely that that information would be available online.

Comment: Sort of if I can pass the immigration then it is okay. (I have visa on arrival for free there)

Comment: You may ask it to your local consular/embassy, possibly when you apply for the tourist visa (and I expect you should really prove that you will do tourism. Usually if you are banned, they tell you (e.g. when you exit/deported).

Comment: Azerbaijan actually publishes a black list of travellers banned the country.

Answer (score 3):

The UAE [doesn't have an online Blacklist available](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-check-a-blacklist-for-the-UAE).

However, [suggested courses of action include](https://www.thenational.ae/business/checking-if-you-are-blacklisted-in-the-uae-is-straightforward-1.113461):

> the quickest course of action is to ask a friend in the UAE to visit a
>   police station with a copy of your passport, and ideally a letter of
>   authority, to enquire if there are any cases or complaints registered.
>   They will not be told details, just if there are any cases on file.